# php and MYSQL SELECT issues with arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if you could tell me what is wrong with my code or point out where I am going wrong, as I am not able to display any results. $_POST['checkbox'] is an array.

```
<?
   $get_id=$_POST['checkbox']; 

    if(empty($get_id)) {
        echo("<h3>You didn't select anything.</h3>");
   } else {  
        $where[]  = sprintf(" id='%s'",$_POST["checkbox"]);
   }

   $where_str = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$where);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM products $where_str";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Description</th> </tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr><td>";     
            echo $row['description'];   
            echo "</td></tr>"; 
        }
   echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Did you echo your query to see what it looks like? It If `$_POST['checkbox']` is an array, then you need to loop over it. Otherwise, you are getting `id=Array AND id=Array`...  Also, seems like those should be `OR` instead of `AND`, in which case they should be in an `IN ()` clause (after you sanitize against SQL injection)

Comment: [Here are a whole bunch of examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+array+of+checkboxes) of how to transfer that post array into an `IN ()` clause.

Comment: Yes, I have done an echo, and id=Array. How would you create a loop to do this then? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See [PHP Array to select mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112417/php-array-to-select-mysql) But first, you _must_ sanitize against SQL injection.

Comment: As @insertusernamehere mentioned don't use mysql_* functions and also don't use php short tag `<? ?>`

Answer (score 3):

1. You should refrain from using short tags `<?` as they are not supported after PHP 5.4.
2. You are not connecting to MySQL (`$link` undefined)
3. You are using a deprecated API (`mysql_`). See comments for alternatives (`mysqli_` or `PDO`)
4. You should use the `REQUEST_METHOD` index of `$_SERVER` to determine whether your script has been posted.

   `if( $_SERVER[REQUESTED_METHOD] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['checkbox']) ) {`
   `... }`
5. You need to use error handling to check for errors. If you `echo $sql;` you would see that the checkboxes aren't being populated:

   `SELECT * FROM products  WHERE  id=''`
6. Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. When you switch to current API, use binded parameters.
7. Is `$_POST[checkbox]` an array?
8. `sprintf` will not work as you intend it to because you are passing the entire `$_POST[checkbox]` array to it. You would need to iterate through it to format it. (See Ollie's answer)

**Example**

Assuming your HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="post" ...>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And all three boxes are checked; it will produce this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Following Collie's loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {
    $where[]  = sprintf(" id='%s'",$checkbox);
}
```

`$where` will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  id='1'
    [1] =>  id='2'
    [2] =>  id='3'
)
```

The rest of your script should work. However, you should look into using the [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator.

That will enable you to skip the loop and just use `implode`:

```
$where = "'" . implode("', '", $_POST[checkbox]) . "'";
```

Which produces:

```
'1', '2', '3'
```

And combined with `IN`:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM WHERE id IN ($where)";
```

Be aware that this is not sanitized and you're still vulnerable to injection.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. Apologies for not being clear, but link was defined in header file.

$POST_[checkbox] is an array and I have now edited the code accordingly as per Ollie's suggestion, but am still not getting results.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST["checkbox"]` is an array like you say then you cannot use it as a string in the `sprintf`.  Try using `array_pop` to return the last value of that array or similar.

You could `foreach` through each element in the array:

```
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {
    $where[]  = sprintf(" id='%s'",$checkbox);
}
```

Although this will probably just create an invalid SQL statement if asking for ID to be equal to two different integers.